# I know the meaning of the all of the words but I struggle to understand the meaning of the sentence as a whole

Tags: meaning-in-context

Sometimes some sentences are really strange. I know the meaning of the all of the words in the following sentence but I really struggle to understand the meaning of the sentence as a whole:  "Some of this history
reflects unresolved differences being papered over by any evidence that
can be brought to hand" ( emphasis added)

> WDRs have not had a distinguished history of handling
>   empirical evidence; too often bad—or simply incredible—evidence is presented
>   along with useful and interesting new findings. ***Some of this history
>   reflects unresolved differences being papered over by any evidence that
>   can be brought to hand.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I have this problem (in other languages, I'm a native English speaker) I try to structure the sentence through grouping: which words belong to which part of the sentence?

> Some of this history

Subject

> reflects

Primary Verb

> unresolved differences being papered over by any evidence that can be brought to hand.

Direct Obejct

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

> unresolved differences

Object

> being papered over by any evidence that can be brought to hand.

Modifier

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

> being papered over

Verb

> by any evidence that can be brought to hand

Modifier

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

> by any evidence

Prepositional Phrase

> that can be brought to hand

Modifier

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

So from this, we learn that some of this history, i.e. **certain past WDRs** (I'm going to assume that stands for something something *Report*) **show** unresolved differences, i.e. **unsolved problems**, and those unresolved differences are being papered over, i.e. **hidden**, and they are hidden **by** any evidence that can be brought to hand, i.e. **whatever they can find**, the implication being that they frequently find faulty evidence.

Comment: Good answer, and a nice explanation of the methodology to deal with similar sentences.